# Java Multi-Threaded Processes

Tags: java, multithreading, input, process

I'm making a core server-management system for my company, and both the server manager and server itself are Java jar files. What I need to do is boot up the server from the server manager, and the server needs to be able to read console input. However, the way I currently have it coded, it ignores console input. I believe the while loop is freezing the thread, but IDK what to do about it. Any ideas?

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh start.sh");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: For starters, use a `ProcessBuilder`, not `Runtime#exec()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, your while loop isn't freezing the thread - the call to `reader.readLine()` is. I'd recommend you listen to both your `InputStream` and `ErrorStream`, and to do both at the same time you either need to use `Threads` or java NIO. For a `Thread`ed solution, I built and used [DataFetcher](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/) for specifically this kind of purpose. All you need to do is create a `DataFetcher` around an `InputStream`, add a `FetcherListener`, and start the `DataFetcher` with a new `Thread`